Sqlalchemy Pooling not working. What went wrong in my implementation?
Sqlalchemy Pooling is not working. How can I make pooling effective in below configuration?
Even after adding all above parameters in create_engine. I still getting stale connections though pool_recycle time mentioned above is less then db wait_timeout. Connection pooling is not effective.
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, SmallInteger, Column, Integer, String, Float, DateTime

engine = create_engine(DB_URL,
                       pool_size=10,
                       max_overflow=20,
                       pool_timeout=10,
                       pool_recycle=250,
                       pool_pre_ping=True
                       )

Models/models.py
import os
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, SmallInteger, Column, Integer, String, Float, DateTime

# Define the SQLAlchemy engine

DB_URL = "db_string"

engine = create_engine(DB_URL,
                       pool_size=10,
                       max_overflow=20,
                       pool_timeout=10,
                       pool_recycle=250,
                       pool_pre_ping=True
                       )
# Define a declarative base
Base = declarative_base()

# Define a model class
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String(1000), nullable=False)
    password = Column(String(1000), nullable=False)
    # token = Column(String(1000), nullable=False)
    # token_generation_time = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    client = Column(String(1000), nullable=False)
    jwt_token = Column(String(2000))
    is_enable = Column(SmallInteger)

# Create the tables in the database
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

# Create a sessionmaker to create sessions with the database
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

# Create a session
session = Session()

main.py
# initializing size of string
import time
import os
import jwt
import json
import pyotp
import qrcode
import base64
import hashlib
import logging
from service import ServiceLayer
from flask_limiter import Limiter
from Models.models import session
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from flask_limiter.util import get_remote_address
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, send_file, make_response

app = Flask(__name__)
service_layer = ServiceLayer()

@app.route(f'{BASE_URL}/list_users', methods=['GET'])
def list_user():
    try:
        user_list = service_layer.get_all_users(session)
        return_data = jsonify({'users': user_list})
        return return_data
    except Exception as e:
        session.rollback()
        logger.info(f"Some error while Listing Users - Try Again !! - {e}")
        return make_response("Some error while Listing Users - Try Again - Contact Admin!!", 401)


The problem is probably in how you use this pool. Could you provide a Minimal reproducible example?

added reproducible example, please help me out

In your code example you are using the same session instance for all endpoint calls.
Your endpoints are being called in different threads. So, they can be executed in parallel. But session can't be used concurrently.
Consider using Flask-SQLAlchemy package. It simplifies session management for Flask apps.
https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com

I donot see its effective. Its same as SQLAlchemy. One way to have persistent connection is to have session at each api level but that have more overhead compare to connection pooling methodology.

I think Flask-SQLAlchemy is more about simplicity rather than effectiveness. You will definitely be able to achieve higher performance by using raw SQLAlchemy, but it's harder to learn it. Flask-SQLAlchemy addresses some common issues and therefore it's easier to use.

As I underastand, Flask-SQLAlchemy uses connection pooling. So, I don't understand your comment about "overhead compare to connection pooling methodology". In your code example you don't use pooling. You are using one session per worker (session is global object), which is wrong (you need to use one session per connection).

If you want to use raw SQLAlchemy, read about scoped_session. I think that's what you need. And you need to create sessions using scoped sessionmaker every time you need it instead of using global session object.

yeah whatever I showed shows global session. Thats wrong. I have replaced global session with local api specific session that solved stale connection problem but based on above sqlalchemy and flask_alchemy implemenation I donot see connection pooling at database level. As api specific session creation solves stale connection problem but leads to overhead for each api request when users are in bulk. Connection Pooling is still not working even with Flask_Sqlalchemy !!

SQLAlchemy sessions are not thread-safe. As I understand, you need to use kind of separate connection pool for each thread of your app. Either scoped sessions or Flask-SQLAlchemy can help you solve this. But, considering the mentioned limitation, it will not be very efficient. If you care about performance, consider switching to FastAPI with async endpoints and async SQLAlchemy connections

still I donot understand why this implemenation not giving connection pools ??engine = create_engine(DB_URL,                        pool_size=10,                        max_overflow=20,                        pool_timeout=10,                        pool_recycle=250,                        pool_pre_ping=True                        )

The line Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine) creates connection pool, but you use it only once to get global session and then you are using that global session object everythere. You should create new session objects inside your endpoints with session = Session() instead of just using global session object

My code itself working fine, pooling working fine. Session is handled at API level rather global session.
